# self.name.text value change from another view controller gives fatal error:

Tags: ios, string, swift3

I have `viewcontroller` and `subviewcontroller` I want to change self.name.text from `subViewController` `changeIt` function , to inside `viewcontroller` gives me

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

How can I resolve it , my codes under below.

**subViewController**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class subViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      if prefs.string(forKey: "session") == "yes" {

         let newname = prefs.string(forKey: "name") 
         ViewController().changeIt(name : newname)

    }else{

    }

    }



}
```

**ViewController**

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!


    class func sharedInstance() -> ViewController {

        struct Singleton {
            static var sharedInstance = ViewController()
        }

        return Singleton.sharedInstance
    }

       override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()



        }


    public function changeIt(name : String){

    print("New Name \(name)") /// WORKS!!

    self.name.text = "\(name)" /// GIVES FATAL ERROR


}



    }
```

(*ViewController also inside ContainerView)

Comment: Have you connected your outlet of `name` from your storyboard??

Comment: `ViewController()` doesn't initialise the view. You need load the view from either XIB or Storyboard

Comment: @BadhanGanesh yes connected

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar dude this my view controller also  inside container view

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set the IBOutlet directly from another controller instead declare a variable `var tempName` set that in your previous controller and use this variable to set your textfield `self.name.text = tempName`  Hope this helps you